# Remove class when clicking outside of div (including children)

Tags: jquery

I am using the below code to init `removeClass()` when I click outside of a specific `div`. However, in practise, this is only effecting this `div` directly, and not any children inside of it. Obviously when clicking on the parent, you are actually clicking on the children, rather than the parent directly.

Is there a way to edit the below jQuery so it includes clicking anywhere inside of that parent `div`?

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is(parentDiv) === false ) {

        // Remove all classes
        otherDiv.removeClass();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with checking if the current target is not same as `parentDiv`, you can additional checked if any of the targets are also not descendants of the `parentDiv` using the jQuery [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) method like:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is(parentDiv) && parentDiv.has(e.target).length === 0) {

    // Remove all classes
    otherDiv.removeClass();
  }
});
```

Basically, if `e.target` is a descendant of the `parentDiv`, then `parentDiv.has(e.target).length` will return a non-zero value, else it will return 0.

**Demo:**

```js
const parentDiv = $('#parent')
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  console.clear();
  if (!$(e.target).is(parentDiv) && parentDiv.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    console.log('Clicked Outide #parent')
  }
});
```

```css
#parent{background:#99c0c3;width:160px;height:120px;position:relative}
#child{background:#ffde99;width:50%;height:50%;position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%)}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Click outside parent, inside parent and inside child
</p>
<div id="parent">parent
  <div id="child">child</div>
</div>
```